# SharePoint Publishing site HTTPModule

Tags: sharepoint-2007, redirect, httpmodule, url-rewriting

I have written an `HTTPModule` for the redirection purpose and installed in GAC and referenced in root `web.config` file. It is working for Team sites very well.

I am using `PreRequestHandlerExecute` to see the request is page or not and calling

```
public void Init(HttpApplication context)
        {
            this.app = context;
            this.app.PreRequestHandlerExecute += new EventHandler(Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute);
        }

void Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute(object source, EventArgs e)
        {
            Page page = HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler as Page;
            if (page != null)
            {
                 page.PreInit += new EventHandler(Perform_Redirection);
            }
        }
```

and in the `Perform_Redirection` method I am doing the redirection stuff.

```
void Perform_Redirection(object source, EventArgs e)
   {
      //logic goes here for redirection
   }
```

The above code working fine for Teamsites but not for Publishing sites. The `Page.PreInit` is not firing for publishing sites.

Please help me to solve this problem!

I am using `PreRequestHandlerExecut`e, because I need session object and other details otherwise I would have used `BeginRequest`.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by moving the redirection code into the PreRequestHandlerExecute event handler

Comment: You should accept this answer if it solved the problem as described.